# Find and Store (Regex, PHP)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, tags

I'm grabbing a list of tags used on a post with the `$posttags` array. In this there's a special tag that I want to store separately: `profile-somename`.

How do I:

1. Find this special `profile-somename` tag from the list (The value after `profile-` is dynamic, keeps changing, `somename` is just an example)
2. Strip `profile-` from it and
3. Store in a separate variable?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like

```
$tags = array('foo', 'bar', 'profile-blah');
$found = preg_grep('~^profile~', $tags);
if($found)
   $profile_name = substr(end($found), strlen('profile-'));
```

ok, it turns out we have array of objects. preg_grep won't work with it, so you have to loop

```
function find_profile_name($posttags) {
   foreach($posttags as $tag)
      if(preg_match('~^profile-(.+)~', $tag->slug, $m))
          return $m[1];
   return null; // no profile-... found
}
```

Comment: Great, almost works, but mine seems to be a multi-dimensional array so the above code doesn't work on it. What should I change in your code for it work on my md array?